# Internet Explorer 9 - Magento Catalog Layout Issue

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, magento, internet-explorer-9

I'm currently trying to figure out an issue with IE9 and magento, the screenshot below explains the issue better (this is fine in Firefox/Opera/Chrome) or here http://foscamuk.co.uk/indoor-ip-cameras.html:

[image: IE9 Catalog Magento Issue]

This is clearly an IE compatibility issue but I have no idea where to start looking, the CSS code is here:

```
.products-grid-container{ background:#fafafa; padding: 5px 0; border:1px solid #ffffff; -webkit-border-radius:5px; -moz-border-radius:5px; border-radius:5px; box-shadow:0 0 3px #ccc; }
.products-grid { position:relative; }
.products-grid li.item { float: left; padding: 15px 5px; width: 160px; text-align:center; position: relative; background:url(../images/bg-li-product.png) 100% 10px no-repeat; }
.products-grid li.last{ background:none; }
.products-grid .product-image { display: block; height: 120px; margin: 0 0 15px 10px; width: 135px; }
.products-grid .product-name { color: #555; margin: 5px 0 17px; padding:0 10px; font-weight:400;  }
.products-grid .product-name a { color: #555; font-size:110%; }
.products-grid .product-name a:hover{color:#D92D37;text-decoration:none; font-weight:400;}
.products-grid .price-box { margin:5px 0; }
.products-grid .availability { line-height:21px; }
.products-grid .actions { background:url(../images/bg-action.png) 50% 100% no-repeat; padding:0 0 30px; }
.products-grid.last .actions{ background:none;}
.products-grid .actions .add-to-links { display:none; }
```

While I've got your attention, also on this page, if you look at the bottom toolbar the list image seems to go below where it should - not entirely sure why this is happening as it is running exactly the same code as the top toolbar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a broken `a` tag in your list items.

When I viewed the source, I found this: `<a href="http://foscamuk.co.uk/foscam-fi9821w.html" class="minimal-price-link">` which was followed by a closing div tag. This should explain your IE issues. :)

Answer (score 1):

You have a Pie.js that is showing some error try to fix it. May be its a conflict issue.Try using noConflict

Answer (score 1):

your a tag is not ended

Check :)